# Exception in Using Hadoop for MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, cloud, elastic-map-reduce

I am facing an exception in using Hadoop on local box.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.addDeprecation(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ConfigUtil.addDeprecatedKeys(ConfigUtil.java:522)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ConfigUtil.loadResources(ConfigUtil.java:40)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.(Job.java:108)
 at wordcount.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:73)

My version for Hadoop is 0.23.7

Comment: are you compiling your mapreduce on the same version of hadoop as which you are running your map reduce? If you compile on version X, it may not run on a hadoop cluster of version Y.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the Hadoop version compatibility. Check the `hadoop` version in the virtual machine that you are using .Thank you.